# How to use common file for android and web application made in codeigniter

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, design-patterns

I am developing an application which would have web version as well as android application.Web application is been made in codeigniter.For android application,I am using php to retrieve data from database.So i just wanted to know is there anyway through which i can use common files for both the application.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by common "file"? Are you talking about the UI or business logic?

business logic: publish your business logic as a web service, and use it from both web, mobile apps.

In case of UI: it depends on the type of your mobile app.

You can load the remote webpage using [webviews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). But it need extra coding to handle back n forth calls between Android activity and webpage.